# Error: ExecuteNonQuery requires an open and available Connection

Tags: c#, ms-access

I'm creating a system which allow the user to input 10 data in text-box controls then save all together in database. But this error got me stock for a while and I don't know where do I go wrong. Can someone help me on this? Please be kind and thank you in advance. Also feel free to edit my question.

Here's my code:

```
private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DateTime getdate = DateTime.Now;
    String time = getdate.ToString("F");
    try
    {
        con.Open();
        var rows = new[]
        {
            new {Item = txtItem.Text, Product = txtProduct.Text, Quantity = txtQuantity.Text},
            new {Item = txtItem2.Text, Product = txtProduct2.Text, Quantity = txtQuantity2.Text},
            new {Item = txtItem3.Text, Product = txtProduct3.Text, Quantity = txtQuantity3.Text},
            new {Item = txtItem4.Text, Product = txtProduct4.Text, Quantity = txtQuantity4.Text},
            new {Item = txtItem5.Text, Product = txtProduct5.Text, Quantity = txtQuantity5.Text},
            new {Item = txtItem6.Text, Product = txtProduct6.Text, Quantity = txtQuantity6.Text},
            new {Item = txtItem7.Text, Product = txtProduct7.Text, Quantity = txtQuantity7.Text},
            new {Item = txtItem8.Text, Product = txtProduct8.Text, Quantity = txtQuantity8.Text},
            new {Item = txtItem9.Text, Product = txtProduct9.Text, Quantity = txtQuantity9.Text},
            new {Item = txtItem10.Text, Product = txtProduct10.Text, Quantity = txtQuantity10.Text}
        };

        foreach (var row in rows)//Check if ItemCode exist
        {
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(row.Item))
            {
                OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(@"Select * from TblInventory where ItemCode='" + txtItem.Text + "'");
                command.Connection = con;
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("itemcode", txtItem.Text);
                OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

                if (reader.Read())
                {
                    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(@"Update TblInventory set Quantity = Quantity + @Quantity WHERE ItemCode = @itemcode");

                    cmd.Connection = con;
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Quantity", Convert.ToInt32(txtQuantity.Text));
                    txtProduct.Text = reader["ProductName"].ToString();
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@itemcode", txtItem.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateAndTime", time);
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();// HERE <<<
                    MessageBox.Show("You added " + txtQuantity.Text + " " + txtProduct.Text, "Existing Item");
                }
            }
            else //Add new Data if Item Code is not exit;
            {
                var rows2 = new[]
                {
                    new {Item = txtItem.Text, Product = txtProduct.Text, Quantity = txtQuantity.Text},
                    new {Item = txtItem2.Text, Product = txtProduct2.Text, Quantity = txtQuantity2.Text},
                    new {Item = txtItem3.Text, Product = txtProduct3.Text, Quantity = txtQuantity3.Text},
                    new {Item = txtItem4.Text, Product = txtProduct4.Text, Quantity = txtQuantity4.Text},
                    new {Item = txtItem5.Text, Product = txtProduct5.Text, Quantity = txtQuantity5.Text},
                    new {Item = txtItem6.Text, Product = txtProduct6.Text, Quantity = txtQuantity6.Text},
                    new {Item = txtItem7.Text, Product = txtProduct7.Text, Quantity = txtQuantity7.Text},
                    new {Item = txtItem8.Text, Product = txtProduct8.Text, Quantity = txtQuantity8.Text},
                    new {Item = txtItem9.Text, Product = txtProduct9.Text, Quantity = txtQuantity9.Text},
                    new {Item = txtItem10.Text, Product = txtProduct10.Text, Quantity = txtQuantity10.Text}
                };

                foreach (var row2 in rows)
                {
                    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(row2.Item) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(row2.Product) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(row2.Quantity))
                    {
                        OleDbCommand cmdInsert = new OleDbCommand(
                                @"insert into TblInventory (ItemCode,ProductName,Quantity,DateAndTime)values(@ItemCode,@ProductName,@Quantity,@DateAndTime)");
                        cmdInsert.Connection = con;
                        cmdInsert.Parameters.AddWithValue("ItemCode", row2.Item);
                        cmdInsert.Parameters.AddWithValue("ProductName", row2.Product);
                        cmdInsert.Parameters.AddWithValue("Quantity", row2.Quantity.ToString());
                        cmdInsert.Parameters.AddWithValue("DateAndTime", DateTime.Now);

                        cmdInsert.ExecuteNonQuery(); HERE <<<
                        MessageBox.Show("You added " + row.Quantity + " " + row.Product, "New Item");
                    }
                }
            }
            showGrid2();
            con.Close();
            clear();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: which Line shows you the error? I mean which `ExecuteNonQuery`

Comment: both command shows an error sir. On the ``Update Statement`` the MessageBox shows first before the error pops up while on the ``else condition``, no messagebox appears only the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my first time answering a question, so go easy on me if I misunderstood something.

From what I can see, at some point `cmdInsert.ExecuteNonQuery();` is called **after** `con.Close();` inside your foreach loop.
Since you call `con.Close();` every time an iteration fulfills the if clause.

Maybe try something like this:

**editted**

```
private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DateTime getdate = DateTime.Now;
            String time = getdate.ToString("F");
            try
            {

                var rows = new[]
                {
                    new {Item = txtItem.Text, Product = txtProduct.Text, Quantity = txtQuantity.Text},
                    new {Item = txtItem2.Text, Product = txtProduct2.Text, Quantity = txtQuantity2.Text},
                    new {Item = txtItem3.Text, Product = txtProduct3.Text, Quantity = txtQuantity3.Text},
                    new {Item = txtItem4.Text, Product = txtProduct4.Text, Quantity = txtQuantity4.Text},
                    new {Item = txtItem5.Text, Product = txtProduct5.Text, Quantity = txtQuantity5.Text},
                    new {Item = txtItem6.Text, Product = txtProduct6.Text, Quantity = txtQuantity6.Text},
                    new {Item = txtItem7.Text, Product = txtProduct7.Text, Quantity = txtQuantity7.Text},
                    new {Item = txtItem8.Text, Product = txtProduct8.Text, Quantity = txtQuantity8.Text},
                    new {Item = txtItem9.Text, Product = txtProduct9.Text, Quantity = txtQuantity9.Text},
                    new {Item = txtItem10.Text, Product = txtProduct10.Text, Quantity = txtQuantity10.Text}
                };
                foreach (var row in rows)//Check if ItemCode exist
                {
                    con.Open();
                    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(row.Item))
                    {
                        OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(@"Select * from TblInventory where ItemCode='" + txtItem.Text + "'");
                        command.Connection = con;
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("itemcode", txtItem.Text);
                        OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

                        if (reader.Read())
                        {
                            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(@"Update TblInventory set Quantity = Quantity + @Quantity WHERE ItemCode = @itemcode");

                            cmd.Connection = con;
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Quantity", Convert.ToInt32(txtQuantity.Text));
                            txtProduct.Text = reader["ProductName"].ToString();
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@itemcode", txtItem.Text);
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateAndTime", time);
                            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();// HERE
                            MessageBox.Show("You added " + txtQuantity.Text + " " + txtProduct.Text, "Existing Item");
                        }
                    }
                    else //Add new Data if Item Code is not exit;
                    {
                        var rows2 = new[]
                        {
                             new {Item = txtItem.Text, Product = txtProduct.Text, Quantity = txtQuantity.Text},
                             new {Item = txtItem2.Text, Product = txtProduct2.Text, Quantity = txtQuantity2.Text},
                             new {Item = txtItem3.Text, Product = txtProduct3.Text, Quantity = txtQuantity3.Text},
                             new {Item = txtItem4.Text, Product = txtProduct4.Text, Quantity = txtQuantity4.Text},
                             new {Item = txtItem5.Text, Product = txtProduct5.Text, Quantity = txtQuantity5.Text},
                             new {Item = txtItem6.Text, Product = txtProduct6.Text, Quantity = txtQuantity6.Text},
                             new {Item = txtItem7.Text, Product = txtProduct7.Text, Quantity = txtQuantity7.Text},
                             new {Item = txtItem8.Text, Product = txtProduct8.Text, Quantity = txtQuantity8.Text},
                             new {Item = txtItem9.Text, Product = txtProduct9.Text, Quantity = txtQuantity9.Text},
                             new {Item = txtItem10.Text, Product = txtProduct10.Text, Quantity = txtQuantity10.Text}
                        };
                        foreach (var row2 in rows)
                        {
                            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(row2.Item) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(row2.Product) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(row2.Quantity))
                            {
                                OleDbCommand cmdInsert = new OleDbCommand(
                                                 @"insert into TblInventory (ItemCode,ProductName,Quantity,DateAndTime)values(@ItemCode,@ProductName,@Quantity,@DateAndTime)");
                                cmdInsert.Connection = con;
                                cmdInsert.Parameters.AddWithValue("ItemCode", row2.Item);
                                cmdInsert.Parameters.AddWithValue("ProductName", row2.Product);
                                cmdInsert.Parameters.AddWithValue("Quantity", row2.Quantity.ToString());
                                cmdInsert.Parameters.AddWithValue("DateAndTime", DateTime.Now);

                                cmdInsert.ExecuteNonQuery(); HERE
                                MessageBox.Show("You added " + row.Quantity + " " + row.Product, "New Item");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    showGrid2();
                    clear();
                    con.Close();
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

Comment: I appreciate the response sir. When I follow what you had said, the error tells that the connection was not close. maybe because the con.open was initialize in the beginning of try catch statement

Comment: Try the newly editted code, I missed the bigger foreach loop, con.Close(); should be outside that.

Comment: sir @Keyur the error was still telling that ``the connection was not close``

Comment: Could you show me where and how you initialize the 'con' variable? Also did you try the code after my update?

Answer (score 0):

use Using to open the connection and it automatically handles the closing of the connection.So the best and efficient practice is to open the connection as late as possible and close it as soon as possible.

```
foreach (var row in rows)//Check if ItemCode exist
                    {

                            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(row.Item))
                            {
                                OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(@"Select * from TblInventory where ItemCode='" + txtItem.Text + "'");
                                using (command.Connection = con)
                                {
                                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("itemcode", txtItem.Text);
                                con.open;
                                OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

                                if (reader.Read())
                                {
                                    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(@"Update TblInventory set Quantity = Quantity + @Quantity WHERE ItemCode = @itemcode");

                                    cmd.Connection = con;
                                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Quantity", Convert.ToInt32(txtQuantity.Text));
                                    txtProduct.Text = reader["ProductName"].ToString();
                                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@itemcode", txtItem.Text);
                                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateAndTime", time);
                                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();// HERE
                                    MessageBox.Show("You added " + txtQuantity.Text + " " + txtProduct.Text, "Existing Item");
                                }
                               }

                    }
            }
    //dont use con.Close anywhere in the code .
```